# flash crash when loading a html with webkitgtk

Tags: linux, flash, webkit, gtk

I use webkitgtk to open a html page with some flash files on it. But when I load the page it crashes. My code is given below. What should I do?

```
GtkWidget *main_window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(main_window), 800, 600);

WebKitWebView *webview = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webkit_web_view_new());
webkit_web_view_set_editable(WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webview),TRUE);
GtkWidget *scrolledWindow = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scrolledWindow),
GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolledWindow), GTK_WIDGET(webview));

g_signal_connect(main_window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroyWindowCb), NULL);
g_signal_connect(webview, "close-web-view", G_CALLBACK(closewebviewCb), main_window);

gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(main_window), scrolledWindow);
webkit_web_view_load_uri(webview,URI_PATH);
/******************webkitsetting************************************/

WebKitWebSettings *settings1 = webkit_web_settings_new ();
g_object_set (G_OBJECT(settings1), "enable-plugins", FALSE, NULL); 
webkit_web_view_set_settings (WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW(webview), settings1);

g_signal_connect (webview, "notify::load-status", G_CALLBACK (loadStatusCb),NULL);
gtk_widget_grab_focus(GTK_WIDGET(webview));
gtk_widget_show_all(main_window);`
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could supply details of how and when this happeans

Comment: I have a few flash videos stored on the server,and my application by opening an html to play video stored on the server.But when the webview of the webkitGTK open, the video does not play.

Comment: It show nothing,black and white.May you help me?

Comment: This code can play videos stored on local host.why it crash on playing html files?

Comment: I'm not a flash developer, my initial comment was to help you improve your question with more details.  As you are not getting any comments, I was going to suggest you offer a bounty.  But that option is not available until you get to a reputation of 70 points.